# lodash groupBy is a long sync operation starving all other async operations

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, lodash

I'm using lodash group by on a large array,
The operation takes a few minutes, which is starving all other async promisees
(since we aren't releasing the context)

Does anyone have suggestions to use a different lib \ modify my use of groupBy to solve this?

Comment: would [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) help?

Comment: I'd recommend fist trying Moderndash's https://github.com/Maggi64/moderndash/blob/main/package/src/array/group.ts and check if it's faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonce groupBy is just

```
function groupBy<T, V extends PropertyKey>(
  list: T[], get: (v:T) => V,
): Record<V, T[]> {
  const r = {} as Record<V, T[]>
  for (const el of list) {
    (r[get(el)] ??= []).push(el)
  }
  return r
}
```

you may easily add an interceptor to wait if it takes too long:

```
async function groupBy<T, V extends PropertyKey>(
  list: T[], get: (v:T) => V,
): Record<V, T[]> {
  const r = {} as Record<V, T[]>
  let now = performance.now()
  for (const el of list) {
    // if `get` is fast, better to smth like `if (i%100==0)` here
    if (performance.now() - now > 10 /*ms*/) {
      // break the execution
      await new Promise(setTimeout) // or whatever waiting function
      now = performance.now()
    }
    (r[get(el)] ??= []).push(el)
  }
  return r
}
```